# Pipe stdout to command on stdout

Tags: process, tail, stdout

If I had a running process like `tail -F watch.txt` and I wanted to capture the `stdout` from this running process and pipe it to another command on stdout how could this be done?

Here's an example of a running process.

```
$ tail -F watch.txt
foo
bar
baz
```

Let's say I wanted to capture the `stdout` and write each of these a new file or process each string with another command. For instance there's this `terminal-notifier` (mac specific) command that takes a message `terminal-notifier --message "$STDOUT_FROM_TAIL"`.

Is this possible with things that already exist within unix?

Comment: Since it is already running, you might have to redirect the file descriptor of that process elsewhere. Try: http://ingvar.blog.redpill-linpro.com/2010/07/10/changing-a-process-file-descriptor-on-the-fly/

Comment: If the problem is to call `terminal-notifier` for each new line that `tail -f` reports, have a look at `xargs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assuming you can restart the program** and put it in a pipe, you can then pipe it to `xargs`, with the following caveats:

- you want to run the command one line at a time (-n 1)
- you want to put the output inside a parameter (-i)
- you probably want the message to run as soon as the `tail` reports it, so you need `tail` to be *line buffered*.

Depending on what you have installed:

```
stdbuf -o 0 tail -f FILE | xargs -i -n 1 terminal-notifier --message "{}"

unbuffer    tail -f FILE | xargs " "
```

and I saw a `tailf` version that supported the `-l` (line-buffered) option.

You can also emulate `tail -f` in Perl.

And you can replace `xargs` (even if it's pretty standard and ubiquitous) with a specially crafted `for` loop in the shell (it's **not** as simple as it looks, though; it's similar to [processing filenames with spaces](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/handling-filenames-with-spaces-in-bash.html) in a loop).

If you cannot restart the program, you need to intercept its stdout. Here's [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323956/how-to-redirect-output-of-an-already-running-process) about that. Other utilities and scripts such as [reredirect](https://github.com/jerome-pouiller/reredirect/) are described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/473240/redirect-stdout-while-a-process-is-running-what-is-that-process-sending-to-d/535938#535938); I don't know about their compatibility with MacOS, though.

## Further modifications

The output can be parsed normally with utilities such as sed or cut:

unbuffer    tail -f FILE | grep animal | sed -e 's/animal (.*) gear/\1/' | xargs ...

This way we would have:

```
Output by tail                      output by grep        output by sed
correct horse battery staple
animal rhino gear                   animal rhino gear     rhino
llama is animal                     llama is animal       llama is animal
llama peruvian                      
animal ant gearbox                  animal ant gearbox    antbox
```

(`--line-buffered` option to `grep` may be used)

Comment: I can restart the program. However I'm on mac and don't have `stdbuf` or `unbuffer` installed. Should I install one of those or is there another alternative caked into OSX?

Comment: Do you have Perl installed? I can amend the answer tomorrow morning.

Comment: Just got stdbuf installed but I'm getting `xargs: illegal option -- i` ideas?

Comment: I don't have a Mac, but check with xargs -h or --help how to set up a replacement pattern. Could be -R "{}" for example.

Comment: `echo a b c d e f | xargs -I letter -n 1 terminal-notifier -message letter` I got this example to work :)

Comment: One last question! Let's say I have a process that's outputting `animal sheep` then `food pizza` then `animal rhino` then `food hotdog` how do I just have xargs run on `animal` and how do I parse out the animal string using regex `/^animal (.+)$/ig`?

Comment: You can just add a pipe with sed:  `...| sed -e 's/^animal \(.*\)$/\1/ig' |...` will take "animal chameleon" and output "chameleon". I've updated the answer with a slightly different example, which also does filtering. You may want to filter out unmodified lines by piping a further `grep -v animal` after sed, to kill those lines that while containing *animal*, did not match sed's regex. **note**: my own sed does not accept "(.+)" (one or more) and wants "\(..*\)" (one followed by zero or more). Apparently mine doesn't do plusses.

Comment: With some editing between differences for mac, I got it running with `theme-watch | grep Recieved --line-buffered | sed -E -l -e 's/Recieved Update event on (.+)/\1/' | xargs -I file terminal-notifier -message file` Thanks!